# Use the Maven Assembly Plugin to create an archive, then store that in the project, then tag the project doing a release in Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, plugins

Is there a way to have an archive that is made by the Maven Assembly Plugin, to be added to the project and included in the project jar file when it is deployed?

I have a maven project.  I am attempting to do a "Release" of the project via Jenkins.  Using the Maven Assembly Plugin, I am able to generate an archive that gets deployed to a Nexus repository when I do a Maven Release in Jenkins.  **That is good, but I also want the archive to reside in the original project, so that when the release does "git tag", the project contains the archive.**  I noticed that Jenkins does a "git tag -F" prior to invoking use of the Maven Assembly Plugin.  Therefore, it doesn't seem that, with my current setup, Jenkins can store the archive in the project via the git tag, since the archive won't have existed yet.

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject && git tag -F /var/folders/2r/1234abcd/T/maven-scm-123456789.commit my-project-0.0.1
```

... then later ...

```
[INFO] [INFO] maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (make-assembly) @ my-project
[INFO] [INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
[INFO] [INFO] Building zip: /Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject/target/checkout/target/my-project.zip
[INFO] [INFO] Building tar: /Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject/target/checkout/target/my-project.tar.gz
```

Next is the portion of the pom.xml file regarding the Maven Assembly Plugin.  I have the phase set to "install" here.  Also, the Jenkins configuration is set to do a build with "mvn package".  This is good, because if I do a Jenkins build, the Assembly Plugin won't be triggered. Only if I do a Jenkins release will the Assembly plugin be triggered, since after "mvn package", it does a "mvn install".  However, this might work against the question I am posing about:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    <finalName>my-project</finalName>
    <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is the assembly.xml file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <!-- file formats to use when archiving: zip, tar.gz, etc.-->
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <!-- location of the files to archive-->
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/myfilestoarchive</directory>
      <!-- do not include folders/subfolders in the final archive -->
      <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
      <!-- set permissions for all the files in the archive -->
      <fileMode>0777</fileMode>
      <!-- file types to include -->
      <includes>
        <include>*.xml</include>
        <include>*.jsp</include>
      </includes>
      <!-- specific files to leave out of archive -->
      <excludes>
        <exclude>README.txt</exclude>
        <exclude>NOTICE.txt</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Is the solution simply to set the phase for the Maven Assembly to be prior to "mvn package"?  But then also, how do I get the plugin to place the archive in the project?

Comment: `git tag` applies to the Git repo. Generally zip/tar packages (or other binary artifacts such as jars/wars) are not committed to SCM repos. They are published to artifact repositories such as Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: @user944849, thanks for the reply.  The zip/tar package I wish to commit to SCM repo is composed of text files, so it's not a binary artifact (jar/war).  The zip/tar package is for reference, with the goal of putting it into a docs/ folder in the project.  It occurs to me that I can possibly use a shell script to do "mvn assemble:single" and then move the result to the project, prior to Jenkins doing "mvn package" in the build step.  Then the build step would generate a jar file, with the zip/tar package inside of it.  Is that feasible?

Comment: As soon as you make it a zip, it's a package, and an artifact repository is the proper location for it. Anything else, you will be fighting Maven, as it was not really designed for what you're attempting.